# Is there something similar to node-git for python?

Tags: python, git

http://github.com/creationix/node-git
Reading blog posts from a repository. If not, how would you do it (chaching, ...)?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's [Dulwich](http://samba.org/~jelmer/dulwich/), "a pure-Python implementation of the Git file formats and protocols," and [GitPython](http://gitorious.org/git-python), which is apparently a wrapper around the `git` command line tools.